# Saving boundary (e.g. polygon boundary) to variable when using fusion tables?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have an overlay layer created using fusion tables. I am retrieving values from the table using:

```
var vname = e.row['l_name'].value;
```

and this is working correctly. I click on one of the many polygons in the overlay layer and am able to retrieve information related to it. I want to know, is it possible to use geometry column in the same manner?

```
var vgeom = e.row['geometry'].value;
```

This gives me error "TypeError: e.row.geometry is undefined". What I want to do is to save the polygon boundary on which I have clicked and perform some operation on this polygon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [`FusionTablesCell`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/fusion-tables#FusionTablesCell) does not seem to support getting the `geometry` fields for tables. However, instead of using the Maps Javascript API to access your Fusion Table, you could look into the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference), specifically the [`DataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) object for access your geometry data with a query, returning KML depending on your table. You can then use the [geoxml3 library](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) to parse the KML and store a [`Polygon`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/polygon#Polygon) object.

Here's a [simple sample JSbin](http://jsbin.com/duxitihiwa/edit?html,output). The logic is that the polygon for Nova Scotia is queried from the Fusion Table, being returned as a KML string. This string is not fully correct KML, so the standard elements for a KML file are added to the string. The string is then passed to the geoxml3 parser and added to the map, along with some simple styling. Do note that the parser takes a while to parse the KML. The pertinent code:

```
var query = "SELECT 'Place' as Place, 'geometry' as geom " +
  "FROM 1GK_AefKlsiBzyufbFDuRqvF9RZTdJOUXqnIiCaO9 " +
  "WHERE 'Place' =  'Nova Scotia'";

var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
  'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

gvizQuery.send(function(response) {
  var table = response.getDataTable();
  var geo = table.getValue(0,1);
  geo = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1"><Document><Placemark>' +
    geo + '</Placemark></Document></kml>';
  var parser = new geoXML3.parser({map:map});
  parser.parseKmlString(geo,parser.docs);    
  parser.docs[0].gpolygons[0].setOptions({fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.5});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new numeric formula column such as "poly" and set it to point to "geometry".

```
var vgeom = e.row['poly'].value;
```

it return the geometry as a string such as <...>lng,lat ... lng,lat that you can parse into something useful with

```
function getPolygon( parseable ) { /* <...><coordinates>lng,lat lng,lat</coordinates></...> */
        var poly = [];
        var coordsArray = parseable.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').split( ' ' );
        for ( var i = 0; i < coordsArray.length; i++ )
        { 
            var coords = coordsArray[i].split( "," );
            poly.push( new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat( coords[1] ), parseFloat( coords[0] ) ) ); 
        } 
        return poly;
      }
```

you can also handle holes if you add something like:

```
function getPolyShape( parseable ) { /* <outerBoundaryIs>...<coordinates>border</coordinates>...</outerBoundaryIs><innerBoundaryIs>...<coordinates>hole1</coordinates>...</innerBoundaryIs><innerBoundaryIs>...<coordinates>hole2</coordinates>...</innerBoundaryIs> */
    var poly = [];
    var border = parseable.split( '</outerBoundaryIs>' );
    poly.push( getPolygon( border[0].replace( /<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '' ) ) );
    var holes = border[1].split( '</innerBoundaryIs>' );
    for ( var i = 0; i < holes.length - 1; i++ ) {
        poly.push( getPolygon( holes[i].replace( /<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '' ) ) );
    }
    return poly;
  }
```